# Cytoscape.js directive not invalidating dimensions when container is resized

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cytoscape.js

I have a cytoscape.js graph inside an angular.js directive listening (watching) for it's container div width. when I'm collapsing a side panel in my app, the container div takes the whole width of the screen, then a `$watch` should run, and do a `cy.resize()`, however it's not done as I hoped it would.

in my link function i'm calling the container

```
var container = angular.element(document.querySelector('#cy'));
```

it works, i'm getting the container, and setting up the graph and it's showing fine.

then later, when container div width changes

```
scope.$watch(function () {
        return document.querySelectorAll("#cy")[0].clientWidth;
    }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
            if (typeof cy.resize === 'function') {
                cy.resize();
            }
        }
    });
```

the $watch runs as it should, the div does get wider but the container just moves aside to the newly clear area. the map isn't invalidated on `.resize()`, what I get is that the mouse position is calculated wrong. when I re-size the browser window it does resize properly (as the docs mention).

how can I force a resize in my case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long try and miss streak, we ended up doing this process

1. in the controller we hooked up to the `window.onresize()` event. because we used `controllerAs` we had to define a scope an object to watch a boolean that went true when the window got sized to a larger width, using a getter and a setter, like so

   ```
   Object.defineProperty(vm, "toggleNav", {
           get: function () {
               return navToggled;
           },
           set: function (newValue) {
               navToggled = newValue;
               if (angular.isFunction(vm.resizeControl.onresize)) {
                   vm.resizeControl.onresize();
               }
           }});
   vm.resizeControl = {};
   ```
2. in the directive we watched for the scope property (`resizeControl`) change

   ```
   scope.resizeControl.onresize = function () {
       if (angular.isObject(cy) && angular.isFunction(cy.resize)) {
           $timeout(function () {
               cy.resize();
           });
       }
   };
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that your listener set up through Angular isn't working as you expect.  Angular is not a reliable way to set up listeners, unless everything you're listening to lives in Angular's model and updates *in sync* with Angular's update cycle.  That's a lot of restrictions, and I don't think Angular will work for what you want here.

Bind to proper events instead, or call `cy.resize()` in each of your functions that resizes the div.